# SQL combining nested select query with another query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm having some trouble combining the two following queries that are related to the same item:

1)

```
select inventory.itemnum as itemnum, item.description as itemdesc,
inventory.minlevel as olevel , invcost.avgcost
from inventory join invcost on inventory.itemnum = invcost.itemnum
join item on inventory.itemnum = item.itemnum
where inventory.location = 'CENTRAL' AND inventory.itemnum = 'XMP-3500';
```

This query fetches general  info about the item

2)

```
select SUM(balvalues) from
(
    select INVBALANCES.CURBAL as balvalues from invbalances join inventory
    on invbalances.itemnum = inventory.itemnum and invbalances.location =
    inventory.location where inventory.itemnum = 'XMP-3500'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT -1 * SUM(QUANTITY) from matrectrans where itemnum = 'XMP-3500'
    and TRANSDATE >= '16-SEP-99' and tostoreloc = 'CENTRAL'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT -1 * SUM(QUANTITY) from matusetrans where itemnum = 'XMP-3500'
    and TRANSDATE >= '16-SEP-99' and storeloc = 'CENTRAL'
);
```

And the second calculates the balance of that item at a certain date.

I want to be able to display the result of the second query as a column in the first

Answer (score 0):

Try  like this ..

```
select * from (select inventory.itemnum as itemnum, item.description as itemdesc,
inventory.minlevel as olevel , invcost.avgcost
from inventory join invcost on inventory.itemnum = invcost.itemnum
join item on inventory.itemnum = item.itemnum
where inventory.location = 'CENTRAL' AND inventory.itemnum = 'XMP-3500'; ) 
table1 join (select SUM(balvalues),itemnum from
(
    select INVBALANCES.CURBAL as balvalues,inventory.itemnum as itemnum from
    invbalances join inventory
    on invbalances.itemnum = inventory.itemnum and invbalances.location =
    inventory.location where inventory.itemnum = 'XMP-3500'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT -1 * SUM(QUANTITY) from matrectrans where itemnum = 'XMP-3500'
    and TRANSDATE >= '16-SEP-99' and tostoreloc = 'CENTRAL'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT -1 * SUM(QUANTITY) from matusetrans where itemnum = 'XMP-3500'
    and TRANSDATE >= '16-SEP-99' and storeloc = 'CENTRAL'
) table2 on table1.itemnum= table2.itemnum
```

Comment: I tried your above query but it gives me:
ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns.

Even though I checked that individually they give the same number

Comment: I believe it's coming from this line:
(select SUM(balvalues),itemnum from

Since itemnum is not accessible. How can I go around this?

Comment: @AuthenticReplica can u create sql fiddle